# why UV texture seems to be translucent on renders?

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I have to model/texture a 4mob and have a curious problem with UV texture render. I have a UV texture representing really black lines and icons on a grey background.

[image]

In the Blender's 3D view, the texture appears normally (grey background with black drawing)

[image]

The problem appears when rendering the image, the contrast is very low, like if the texture was translucent (grey background with dark grey drawing).

[image]

Is someone able to explain what can cause this?

NOTE:
I use the internal Blender render engine and do not know anything about Cycle. 
Here is a screenshot of my material settings:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the texture settings:

[image]

Comment: Do you use Blender Render or Cycles? Could you post your Material and Texture settings?

Comment: Is there a way to copy material and texture settings and to copy them in text format or have I to manually write each setting value? in the second case have you got an idea of which settings are relevant? manually write each setting could take a lot of time... (please excuse, my noobism ;) )

Comment: I assume you're using Blender Internal Render. Just make a screencast of your Material and Texture headers (example here: http://math.hws.edu/graphicsbook/a2/blender-material-properties.png).

Comment: I juste edited the question

Comment: OK, please post the Texture settings also (example: https://wiki.blender.org/uploads/thumb/a/a1/Manual-Part-I-Quick38v25.png/200px-Manual-Part-I-Quick38v25.png).

Comment: Maybe you should also post your .blend file via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I guess it'll be the fastest way to find the solution for your issue.

Comment: Thank you @Paul Gonet but I just find what was causing this lack of contrast. See the answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just find what was causing my problem: the white specular.

Lowering the specular intensity and darkening it actually solved the "issue":

[image]

Comment: Good to hear you've found the solution :).